# Mocking a connection to a data source inside a function with Moq?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq

I'm starting to use Moq and I cannot figure out how to test the method **Execute** in the code below:

I have the following class:

```
public class MyObject {
    private IDataReaderPlugin m_source;
    private IDataWriterPlugin m_dest;
    private string[] m_dummyTags = new string[] { "tag1", "tag2", "tag3"};

    public void Execute(DateTime time)
    {
        DataCollection tags = m_source.SnapshotUtc(m_dummyTags, time);

        //Doing some treatment on the values in tags    

        m_dest.Write(tags); 
    }
```

}

Another method is responsible to create and initialize IDataReaderPlugin and IDataWriterPlugin from information in a configuration file.

I want to test the method Execute. So, I need to mock **m_source** and **m_dest** and after I want to test the result sent to **m_dest**.

How I can achieve this with Moq?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should get you started:

```
DateTime myDate = DateTime.Now;

DataCollection tags = new DataCollection();

Mock<IDataReaderPlugin> dataReaderPlugin = new Mock<IDataWriterPlugin>();
dataReaderPlugin.Setup(drp => drp.SnapshotUtc(It.IsAny<string[]>(), myDate)).Returns(tags);

Mock<IDataWriterPlugin> dataWriterPlugin = new Mock<IDataWriterPlugin>();
dataWriterPlugin.Setup(dwp => dwp.Write(tags);    

MyObject mo = new MyObject();
mo.Execute();

mock.Verify(foo => foo.Write(tags));
```

Comment: As far as I know, you can't actually do It.IsAny<string[]>()... I've never found a great way around this :/

Comment: Yeah, the answer was from my memory. You should be able to create a dummy string[] and then pass that in.

Answer (score 4):

```
[Test]
public void ShouldWriteToMDest()
{
   // Arrange
   var mockDest = new Mock<IDataWriterPlugin>();
   var mockSource = new Mock<IDataReaderPlugin>();
   string[] m_dummyTags = new string[] { "tag1", "tag2", "tag3"};

   mockSource.Setup(source => source.SnapshotUtc(m_dummyTags, It.IsAny<DateTime>()).Returns(/*whatever you need*/);

   var myObj = new MyObject(mockSource.Object, mockDest.Object);

   // Act
   myObj.Execute(DateTime.Now);


   // Assert
   Assert.That(mockSource.Object.WhateverPropertyContainsOutput == /*Whatever you need */);

}
```

Comment: As it stands, unless you can inject your interface classes into your MyClass, it's untestable anyway, since your class will be creating them.  You need to use a constructor like what I've shown in my code example to inject the dependencies.

Answer (score 2):

*"Another method is responsible"* - this is the crucial bit of information. If you are using an IoC or DI framework then you'll need to insert some Moq mocks of the interfaces `IDataReaderPlugin` and `IDataWriterPlugin`. Then the `Execute` method will use these mocks supplied by the IoC/DI framework.

If they are simply set by a setter or property then it's as simple as:

```
// Arrange
var mo = new MyObject();
var srcMock = new Mock<IDataReaderPlugin>();
src.Setup(src => src.SnapshotUtc(It.IsAny<string[]>(), It.IsAny<DateTime>()))
   .Returns(new DataCollection() /* or whatever */);
mo.SetSource(srcMock.Object);
// ... same for m_dest
// Act
mo.Execute(DateTime.Now);
// Assert
// assert something... srcMock.Verify() or whatever
```

Comment: Unfortunately, how the class is designed, the 2 interfaces are created inside the class so I cannot inject the mocked interfaces.